# Objective C - How to create an array and new method

Tags: objective-c

I would like to create simple screensaver for learning objective c. 
Screen saver should work in this way:

1. Initialize array with state of rectangles
2. Randomly change parameters of rectangles, color or size for example
3. Draw screen with animateOneFrame
4. Goto to 2

here is my code in animateOneFrame (here I just draw rectangles and change it color)

```
NSBezierPath *path;
NSRect rect;
NSSize size;
NSColor *color;

size = [self bounds].size;

for (int w=0; w<size.width; w=w+40)
{
    for (int h=0; h<size.height; h=h+40)
    {
        if (SSRandomIntBetween( 0, 1 ) == 0)
            color = [NSColor blackColor];
        else
            color = [NSColor whiteColor];
        [color set];
        rect = NSMakeRect(w, h, 40, 40);
        path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
        [path fill];

    }
}
```

Questions:
Where can I create array to use it values in animateOneFrame method?
How can I create my own method which should change some values in array and how I can use it animateOneFrame method?

I try create new method in my *.m file like this

```
 - (void)changeArrayValue(int value, int arrayPosNumber)
{

}
```

but get en error "Expected method body";

Comment: I know that "read the docs" is not usually an appropriate response, but in this case I really think it is. Please head on over to the [Apple Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com) and check out the sample code there. If you continue to have problems then post here with more questions.

Comment: If you can give me a link to a screen saver example in ADC library it would be nice, because I can not find any example corresponding to my case

Comment: You don't really need that. You just need to understand application flow and array manipulation, which are the more general cases of your problem.

Comment: So can you help me with straight answer or you can only send me to read docs (it is not easy to me because all docs in english)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and specifically, `-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`.

Comment: I know that :) I don`t understand where I should initialize it, because if I do it in animateOneFrame, it will initialize every frame, but I want initialize it only once at the screensaver start